# SQL Profiler cant catch Deadlock Graph Event

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to resolve deadlocks. My Application gets deadlocks all the time when there is more then 10 users at the same time.
I have tried with SQL profiler and can't figure it out.

The thing is, in SQL Profiler I have checked to use the Deadlock Graph Event. But when I run the trace the event never got logged. I can see there are many Deadlocks and Deadlock Chains, but none Deadlock Graph. Please advice.
Thanks for help

Comment: What version is the instance you are profiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have only Locks->Deadlock graph selected if you want to see Deadlock graph event only.

Answer (score 4):

When you run set up a filter for database name or database id, the DeadlockGraph event is not captured, even if you don't check "Exclude rows that don't check values".

If you filter for, say, Duration or NTUserName, which neither are populated by DeadlockGraph, the event is included (as long as you don't filter for the database, that is.)

Likewise, if you add LockAcquired and filter for DatabaseName (not populated by LockAcquired), the event is included.

So the problem is with this precise combination.

Refer: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/240737/filtering-for-database-name-id-filters-out-deadlock-graph-when-it-shouldnt